# How to find EC2 instances that have "null" for the PublicIpAddress?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

When I run ...

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --region=us-west-1 \
> --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped \
> Name=ip-address,Values=null \
> Name=block-device-mapping.status,Values=attached \
> --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,PublicIpAddress,BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.VolumeId]"
```

I get back ...

```
[]
```

If I take out the filter `Name=ip-address,Values=null` I get this back ...

```
[
    [
        "i-XXXXX",
        null,
        [
            "vol-f6f6f6f"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "i-d4XXXX8b",
        "XX.XX.XXX.XX",
        [
            "vol-0ca0ca0ca"
        ]
    ],
```

How can I just get those EC2 instances that just have "null" for the PublicIpAddress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no `public-ip`, that filter doesn't seem to work.

Instead, I notice that such instances seem to have this entry:

```
"PublicDnsName": "",
```

Therefore, you should be able to use this logic:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[?PublicDnsName==``].InstanceId'
```